# Is the asymptotic cone $\{0\}$?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-cone

I am studying convex analysis at home for self-learning. I focus especially on the structure of closed convex sets. I came across a weird definition of an asymptotic cone in a French (Sorbonne) university handbook:
Let $E$ be a normed VS of a finite demension. We consider in the augmented vector space $\hat{E}=E\oplus\mathbb{R}$ the convex $\hat{C}=C\times\{1\}$ (obtained by translation from the convex $C=C\times\{0\}$), and the convex cone $\Gamma(C)=cone\hat{C}=\bigcup_{\lambda\geq0}\lambda\hat{C}$.

> We call an asymptotic cone of a convex set $C$ the closed convex cone $C_{as}$ such that:
> $$\overline{\Gamma(C)}\cap(E\times\{0\})=C_{as}\times\{0\}$$

My question is: Isn't this $C_{as}=\{0\}$? Wouldn't it shrink to a point? This doesn't seem like it's the case because later on the handbook they will define lines, half-lines and directions in this cone. Does any one have any intuition on that? Does it even has any relationship with the defintion of asymptotic (recession) cone on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recession_cone)?

Comment: No, for example, if you take $C=[1,\infty)$ then $C_{as} = [0,\infty)$. Draw a picture and remember that you are taking the closure.

Comment: Thanks @copper.hat for this counter-example!

Comment: But for $\Gamma(C)$, the $\{0\}$ is included right? Just the $]0,\infty)$ is the one who's not, I think. Therefore the closure gives us $[0,\infty)$. Is that right?

Comment: That's correct.